# Javascript function does not execute completely

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp-3.0

I have a javascript function named `showInput()`

And this function executes only till the point where "alert('this runs');" is written.

Another way to explain is, when i try to figure out the error, `I placed the alert function at the same place as in the screenshot, and this alert function did not run`.

What is the error here? I have never seen anything like this happening before.

The function runs for first four commands and then exits.
Could it be because of my RAM because, I am using mint 18 with 80 gigs HDD and 2 GB RAM.
Please help me. I am stuck with this bizarre problem for weeks.
This is the javascript code

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function showInput() {
    document.getElementById('dusername').innerHTML = 
                document.getElementById('username').value;
                 document.getElementById('dfirstname').innerHTML = 
                document.getElementById('firstname').value;
                 document.getElementById('dpassword').innerHTML = 
                document.getElementById('password').value;
                 document.getElementById('dlastname').innerHTML = 
                document.getElementById('lastname').value;
                alert('this run');

                 document.getElementById('dcity').innerHTML = 
                document.getElementById('city').value;

                 document.getElementById('daddress').innerHTML = 
                document.getElementById('address').value;

                 document.getElementById('dpincode').innerHTML = 
                document.getElementById('pincode').value;

                 document.getElementById('dlibname').innerHTML = 
                document.getElementById('libname').value;

                 document.getElementById('dlibcity').innerHTML = 
                document.getElementById('libcity').value;

                 document.getElementById('dlibaddress').innerHTML = 
                document.getElementById('libaddress').value;

}</script>
```

Now the cakephp3 code:

```
  <div class="linker">
  <?= $this->Form->create(); ?>
<!--<form id="loginForm">-->
     <div class="align">
    <div id="firstStep"><br /><br /><br />
    <p id="first">First Step</p>
<?php   echo $this->Form->input('firstname');?>
<?php   echo $this->Form->input('lastname');?>
<?php   echo $this->Form->input('mobile');?>
<?php   echo $this->Form->input('address'); ?>  
<?php   echo $this->Form->input('pincode'); ?>   
        <br/>
       <button type="button"  id="firstBtn" class="next1">Next</button>
    </div>
    <div id="secondStep"><br /><br /><br />
      <p id="second">Second Step</p>
      <?php echo $this->Form->input('lib_name'); ?>
      <?php echo $this->Form->input('lib_city'); ?>
      <?php echo $this->Form->input('lib_address');   ?>
       <button type="button" id="secondBtn" class="next">Next</button>
        <button type="button" id="secondBtnBack">Previous</button>
     </div>
    <div id="thirdStep"><br /><br /><br />
      <p id="third">Third Step</p>
            <?php   echo $this->Form->input('username'); ?>
            <?php   echo $this->Form->input('password'); ?>    
        <button type="button" onclick="showInput();"  id="thirdBtn" class="next" >Next</button>
        <button type="button" id="thirdBtnBack">Previous</button>
    </div>
    <div id="fourthStep">
      <p id="fourth">Fourth Step</p><br /><br /><br />
        Useranme:<br />
        <p><div id='dusername'></div></p>
        Password:<br />
        <p><div id='dpassword'></div></p>
         First Name:<br />
        <p><div id='dfirstname'></div></p>
        Last Name:<br />
        <p><div id='dlastname'></div></p>
        City:<br />
        <p><div id='dcity'></div></p>
        Address:<br />
        <p><div id='daddress'></div></p>
        Pincode:<br />
        <p><div id='dpincode'></div></p>
        Lib Name:<br />
        <p><div id='dlibname'></div></p>
        Lib City:<br />
        <p><div id='dlibcity'></div></p>
        Lib Address:<br />
        <p><div id='dlibaddress'></div></p>    
        <br/>
       <button type="button" id="fourthBtnBack">Previous</button> 
       <input type="submit" id='sub_btn' value='Send Mail!' class="next"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

[This is the screenshot of the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJd7v.png)

Comment: your code must be failing to getElementByID() for some element. check first that all elements you are getting by using getElementByID() are actually available in the html page.

Comment: The problem is most certainly not your RAM or any kind of hardware problem. Try debugging your program by looking for errors in the developer console, and by setting break points.

Comment: Stack Overflow makes it really easy to post code... easier than taking a screenshot, uploading it to imgur, and posting the link to it here. Please post some code.

Comment: Maharshi has a good point. Keep moving that `alert()` up one line at a time until it does execute. When it executes, the line with the problem is right below the `alert()`. Check for typos in your element IDs or missing element IDs or IDs set on the wrong elements.

Comment: you may use exception handlers(try & catch) to know the reason of breakage! [Click here for a w3Schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp). Before that, you need to make syre you have tried all the above suggestions in comments

Comment: @Maharshi i checked the complete program for typos and have checked that all the id exists in the page multiple times but still nothing happens.

Comment: @Vince I already did that, the location at which the alert is right now is the point where the program exits.Anywhere above this point alert runs and anywhere below it the alert does not run and it also dies not run at the place where it is placed right now.

Comment: @Vince when i posted code it wasnt showing color codes, i thought it would be easier for you guys to spot the errors with the color codes

Comment: @Vince have added all the code, now can you please take a closer look?

Comment: Thank you for adding the code. The syntax highlighting here can be a little flaky, but seems to always appear after you actually complete the post. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any experience with CakePHP, but I don't see a `$this->Form->input('city');`, so I think you don't have an element with the ID of `city` (I do see one with `lib_city`).

Since your Javascript tries to read a value from an element with an ID of "city", I think it's failing on that line and not executing anything after that. In fact, if you look at your Javascript console (F12), it'll probably say something to that effect.

If I'm right, don't forget to apologize to Maharshi, who was actually the first one to identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First try to **debug** the error.

1. Comment the alert and check function fully work or not.
2. Put alert one or two lines down and check top code works or not, bottom code works or not.
3. Then you can figure out where is the problem.

Your RAM is not an issue for work like this as i think.

Comment: I already did that, and the place where alert function is right now. it does npt run from here or anywhere below this, alert only runs above the current location. as far as the problem is concerned i dont know what it is but i know that it stops running after 4th command in the function